# What is the meaning of `user=locale` in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm looking at `wp-admin\js\application-passwords.js`and I'm trying to reuse this JS file on the frontend.

But in the code, there's like,

```
    wp.apiRequest( {
        path: '/wp/v2/users/' + userId + '/application-passwords?_locale=user',
        method: 'POST',
        data: request
```

What is `_locale=user` for? Is that for authentication cos I'm looking for a way to send authenticate details to the REST API for each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?_locale=user` is used to ensure the user's locale ***(user's default site language)*** is respected when a REST API request is handled.

It has no auth params, just the language preferences.